# Calculated Column To Display Desired Result

Tags: calculated-column

I have a user with a Document Library called Submissions. Below is an excel example of what the user's library looks like with data:

[image]

The Display Name column is a Calculated Column. The user wants/insists to have the column Display Name to output in a format like **Doe, John** instead of John.doe.

Below is the setting the user had when this request was brought to my attention:

[image]

I told the user it was impossible to output as requested due to it pulling from Employee column and formula is just impossible to do so. I need a second opinion/technical response to further explain why it cannot be done. On the other hand, if I'm wrong and there is a way to output the calculated column Display Name to **Doe, John** can someone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you might run into edge cases which you constantly have to solve

On first sight its:

- get the string after the dot
- Capitalize it
- get the string before the dot
- Capitalize it
- join them with a comma

[*I will now fire up my CalcMaster plugin to come up with a Formula*]

#### Here goes

This is from my (private use only) Calculated Column editor

[image]

#### So all in one column:

```
=PROPER(MID(Employee,FIND(".",Employee)+1,255))
 &", "
 &Proper(MID(Employee,1,FIND(".",Employee)-1))
```

But you have to test for any edge cases against all your Employee names

FYI, You can built these formulas yourself in Excel and use *Named Ranges* for the fieldnames.
The merging of Columns (blue in my CalcMaster) you have to do by hand.

Only a subset of Excel Functions work in SharePoint, I tested all: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. Could you please let me know what the formula is when you can? Thanks!

Comment: Danny you are awesome. Hats off to you sir. Could you clarify what you mean when you say "edge cases" for which I constantly have to solve? Please advise.

Comment: One edge case this Formula does **not** solve is Employee names with two periods. I can't think of others off the top of my head.. guess why they are called edge-cases